# Converting All CapsText on a SSRS report to Title Case Text

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, bids

How to convert Text on a SSRS report to Title Case.
Right now I am using

```
=Strconv(Fields!Title.Value, 3)
```

Which works but in some cases eg.: GEORGIA(GA) is the text coming from DB its converting it to Georgia(Ga). I want it convert like Georgia(GA). I think some kind of Regular expressions need to be used, But I'm not sure  how to do that. 
Is there a way to achieve this from a inbuilt SSRS functions or Writing custom method is the only way?

Any kind of help is much appreciated. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will display `GEORGIA(GA)` as `Georgia(GA)`:

```
=StrConv(Left(Fields!Title.Value, InStr(Fields!Title.Value, "(") - 1), 3)
  & Right(Fields!Title.Value, InStr(StrReverse(Fields!Title.Value), "("))
```

Basically it's splitting the string in two based on `(`, applying `StrConv` to the left side then concatenating the two strings back together.

Maybe not the most concise code ever but does the job with native SSRS functions.